# How to access all of the second elements within a vector that is within a vector?

Tags: clojure

I have the following structure:

```
(def m [[120 2] [123 88] [234 77]])
```

And the value

```
(def z 10)
```

I am wanting to access all of the second elements within the smaller vectors (within `m`) and multiply them by `z` and then store the result with the first element of the vector.

I.e. do the calculation `(* secondvectorelement z)`
And the result would look like `[120 resultofcalculation]`

So far I have tried:

```
(map #(* (second m) z ))
```

But I am stuck on this.
TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user=> (map (fn [v] [(first v) (* z (second v))]) m)
([120 20] [123 880] [234 770])
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `for` [list comphrehension](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) with [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring):

```
(for [[fst snd] m] [fst (* snd z)])
```

Or a different approach with the `map` and `update` functions:

```
(map #(update % 1 * z) m)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(map #(vector (first %) (* (second %) z)) m)
```

In my opinion, no need to def z, so:

```
(map #(vector (first %) (* (second %) 10)) m)
```

Edit: I like @erdos' answer better though

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach:

```
(conj [] (apply min (map #(first %) m)) (apply * (conj (map #(second %) m) z)))
```

If we apply the above to OP's data we get

```
[120 135520]
```

Comment: OP wants to apply a function on each second element vector of vectors. Granted this is not totally clear from the question, but we can assume from the accepted answer.

Comment: Which this answer does. OP says he wants to run `*` against all the second elements of his collection-of-vectors - but what he *doesn't* clearly say is that he (apparently) wants to run `min` against all of the *first* elements of his collection-of-vectors. The latter must be derived from his intended result of `[120 resultofcalculation]`. The code in my answer returns a vector containing both results.